# Copying timeline to new sequence lowers resolution

Tags: premiere

Using Adobe Premiere CS6, when I copy my old timeline to new sequence all the .gif and .jpeg background images including titles lose a lot of a resolution... Both sequences have the same settings, I only increased fps on a new one.

Why?

[image: Comparison of previews]
[image: Sequence 1]
[image: Sequence 2]

Comment: Can you post samples?  Are you sure that the settings for both sequences are the same and that they didn't get altered when you first added content to the sequence?  There is no reason that I can think of for this behavior unless something is missing in the explanation of the problem.

Comment: Oh, one other thought, are you using the adaptive preview?  If you have a slower system, then the added frame rate may cause the preview to drop the resolution so it can keep up with the frame rate, but final output wouldn't be different then.

Comment: Problem isn't in preview, when I create video it is the same quality. Sequence is completely the same. I checked all the settings. Here is the link for before and after pic: [link](http://shrani.si/f/1l/kV/33CFfCpS/untitled.png)

Comment: now that I'm home and have a copy of Premiere in front of me, I see my theory about interpolation was wrong.  It appears that for images, it Interprets the footage as whatever the framerate of the sequence is.  That's why the options were greyed out.

Comment: It looks like this may require some more serious dialog to figure out what we are missing.  If you want to continue in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12905/video-production) I can grant you access to be able to talk despite not normally having high enough reputation yet.

Comment: sure if you still wish to help I can try this chat thing in the morning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your pixel aspect ratio and interlace/progressive choices differ between the two sequences.  What you are seeing is a combination of the interlacing and the change in pixel aspect ratio (which results in the image having to be scaled to a new set of pixels that aren't exactly like the original.

For playback on a TV that supports interlaced video, you won't notice a whole lot of difference, but on a computer or progressive display, it will look funny.  For best quality, you will want to use a progressive, square pixel sequence if you are outputting to PC or to a progressive display (such as 1080P or 720P TV).

The bad news is that it doesn't appear there is a good way to make any changes to the sequence that you need to make while there is content in it, but if you make a new sequence, you can go to the settings tab and specify everything the way that you need them specified.